# If $S = \varnothing$ then does an assumption $\forall A \in S: A \subset B \subset X \implies B \in S$ lead to a contradiction?

Tags: general-topology, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. My reading material defines a filter in $x$ as any set $S \subset P(X)$ s.t. 1.) $\varnothing \not\in S$, 2.) $A, B \in S \implies A \cap B \in S$, 3.) $\forall A\in S:A \subset B \subset X\implies B \in X$. The requirement of $S$ to be non-empty is not specified explicitly and I was wondering whether the situation $S = \varnothing$ would lead to a contradiction with the third assumption, i.e. if there are no elements in $S$ then does it mean, under the third assumption, that every subset of $X$ is part of $S$?

Comment: As the empty set is an element of S, the set S cannot be empty.

Comment: @Wuestenfux is correct.  However, the  definition above  is not the usual definition of "filter".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets#Special_types_of_set_families

Comment: @Wuestenfux Argh, I had forgotten the *not* in the LaTeX code. Please see the edited version.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Just to clarify my previous comment: My reading material asserts that $\varnothing \not\in S$. Therefore, if $S$ were to be empty, would then the third assumption then lead to a contradiction?

Comment: If $S=\varnothing$ then it obeys the 3 rules in your question. The rules 2 and 3 are for $S=\varnothing$ vacuously true. However it is custom to demand that a filter is non-empty (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Definition_of_a_filter) for instance). Rule 1 ensures that $S\neq\mathcal P(X)$. That is not always demanded in a definition. Personally I would in that case speak of a "proper filter".

Answer (score 0):

For any proposition or formula $P,$ the form $\forall x\in S\,(P)$ is an abbreviation for $\forall x\,(x\in S\implies P).$

And $(x\in S\implies P)$ is equivalent to $(\,(\neg x\in S)\lor P\,).$

So when $S=\emptyset$ we have $\forall x\in S\,(P)$ iff $\forall x\, (\,(\neg x\in \emptyset)\lor P \,).$ And $\forall x\,(\,(\neg x\in \emptyset)\lor P \,)$ is true regardless of what $P$ is.